# wso2am API backup (in SVN)

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

Using the WSO2 APIM 2.1.0 we have a few instances (1x default + 2x gateway), where the APIs are synchronized with a SVN repository.

The problem is that after redeployment the API definitions are lost (keeping the databases and the SVN repo), so apparently something is stored in the local filesystem (wso2am-2.1.0/repository/deployment/server/.svn)

question: will be sufficient to backup the .svn folder or do I need to keep more? What "everything" shall we backup to keep the API definitions?

Thank you for any hint

Comment: The question is not very much clear to me. Are you saying you lost the SVN repo? If you can take backups of the SVN repo and you don't need to keep any backup of the files reside in the server folder of the WSO2 carbon server. WSO2 servers are designed in a way that can be redeployed by pointing to the database and the SVN repo.

Comment: Now I see, It was redeploy from WSO2AM 2.0.0 to 2.1.0 and the files (API definitions in the SVN repo) are not compatible anymore (there are different handlers used). As well I assumed that DB and SVN should be enough to keep the data

Comment: Yes there are changes in synapse. Please follow the official migration doc for this - https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Upgrading+from+the+Previous+Release

Comment: Thank you all, until then I just scrapped the old installation and redeployed manually using the swagger files (at least they seems to be compatible :P )